# SendFailedException message: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. Working in a Jenkins freestyle job but not in a pipeline job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Currently I am using the following Jenkins plugin to send emails: https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/.

I have AWS SES configured. I am able to send emails via Jenkins using freestyle jobs [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH9kv.png). However, when I attempt to use a pipeline job

```
stages {
    stage('Ok') {
        steps {
            echo "Ok"
        }
    }
}
post {
    always {
        emailext body: 'A Test EMail', recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']], subject: 'Test'
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

`SendFailedException message: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: nobody@nowhere, address not configured yet <nobody@nowhere>`

Jenkins uses the System Admin e-mail address as the sender address for e-mail notification. We configured this under Manage Jenkins -> Configure System. However, the configuration as code still has the following: `mailAccount: address: "address not configured yet <nobody@nowhere>"`

Comment: So it turns out that the Jenkins UI was not updating the configuration. So we had to manually update the Jenkins CASC with an email address. Now we're able to send emails via Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @user14251179, the **Jenkins UI** sometimes doesn't update the email address configuration. So, here are the detailed steps that you can follow to update the email configurations-

- Move to Jenkins home directory, in my case it was `/var/lib/jenkins`
- Search for the configuration file for **Extended-Email** plugin `hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml`
- Open this configuration file in any code editor and edit `<addresses>address not configured yet &lt;nobody@nowhere&gt;</addresses>` to your required email `<addresses>test@test.com</addresses>`
- Save the configuration and restart the jenkins using https://jenkins-url/restart

Try Sending your email again.